# Australia Programmatically access weather info

Tags: web-services, weather

I am looking for web weather service in Australia to get weather data for a location in Australia. Now we are using MSN Webs Service (weather.service.msn.com) but users are complaining about the data accuracy.
I have compared Australian weather data between MSN and NineMSN and it doesn't match exactly.

Is there any simmilar web service provided by ninemsn or Weatherzone?

Comment: Are you implying that weather data collected at different weather stations is *different*???

Comment: I have just check weather of Yass, NSW using MSN and NineMSN webpages. http://local.msn.com/worldweather.aspx?q=yass-aus&eid=8388216 Result: 20 deg Cel. But ninemsn http://weather.ninemsn.com.au/nsw/southern-tablelands/yass is giving me 26.9 deg cel!!!

Comment: Does ninemsn provide weather webs ervice like msn?

Comment: You have to look at the actual times the readings were taken.  That "Foreca" service used by MSN seems pretty rubbish.  The 20 degrees reading was from 9am, but I'm pretty sure it's after midday already.

Comment: Yes paddy, you are right. DO you know if any other company provide web service like MSN (suitable for Australia)?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using Weatherzone?  Is this for personal use, or are you developing an app that will be used by others?  You could always parse the information directly out of Weatherzone's results page, but you never know when they'll change it (hence me asking if this is just for personal use).  I've heard of people doing that.  In fact I recall answering a StackOverflow question about it once.

Answer (score 0):

All Australian weather data derives from the Australian Bureau of Meteorology.
bom.gov.au